# Troubleshooting load balancers service

Tags: kubernetes, service, load-balancing, portforwarding

I have a load balance service that doesn't respond to URI requests. I've tried to debug the services but everything looks ok. Any idea?
Btw the pods forward the services but this one can not respond to URI requests.
REPO:
https://github.com/alfonso84/Kubernete

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-07T18:03:57Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.103.184.182
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    nodePort: 32357
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: web
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: a4f3016e4f2244b13babc8ac55dce995-699656471.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-07T18:03:56Z"
  generateName: web-5f5cb4bdcc-
  labels:
    app: web
    pod-template-hash: 5f5cb4bdcc
spec:
  containers:
  - image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: httpd
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
```

[Service describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzYUR.png)

Please consider that nodeport and aws hostname is dynamic, in case you notice unmatched.

Comment: Please provide the whole pod and service configuration...

Comment: The yamls looks fine. What is kubectl get svc saying? Does it has an external IP assigned? How did you try to call it?

Comment: Just updated an image from describe service

Comment: @Manuel attached image.

Comment: What happens if you curl one of these endpoints?

Comment: @Manuel those are pods from the YAML in the post. I forwarded those and they respond to him.

Comment: When you say "doesn't respond", what _does_ happen?  What code produced the PNG file you attached?

Comment: @DavidMaze I mean, that the URI from hostname gives me 404 and Loadbalance does not trace that request. As far as I know, this service could connect AWS just with that URI, my doubt is what is happening? does this require an ingress? because the service neither gives me an answer to a curl. Let me know if you need more info about it.

Comment: Service must be loadbalancer, if you want that it is reachable from outside world. Further you have to set a loadbalancerIP in your service. The loadbalancerIP can be a public ip address of your cluster. If you need client ips to reach your nginx, you also should set externalTrafficPolicy to Local. Please check your svc and let me know if this helped.

Comment: @Manuel you mean to add a loadBalancerIP=10.10.10.10 as above (adapt to the IP that was given to you by AWS). And change externalTrafficPolicy to Local?

Comment: If you choose the type loadbalancer it should be assigned an IP address internally one or external one. I see an ingress entry a760b06e0634d4372b4b01ad494b3231-2006752957.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com which sounds for me it should be available from public network. But i can't see an public ip there.

Comment: btw. are you sure that the 404 is not from your nginx?

Comment: Doesn't work @Manuel. I upload the full yaml on git for review. link in the post

Comment: @Manuel also documentation said that define a loadbalancerIP is for AKS.

Comment: @Manuel any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry in currently a bit sick. Tomorrow I could setup same environment in aws, like you did for testing purposes. Maybe I can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @xnextion i tried to setup a k8s cluster. I used the newest version 1.21, public cluster with ip restrictions, added a node group with 2 nodes. i started a nginx pod and exposed it as a service, changed it to LoadBalancer type and got an external IP a4095e0c6a97448c8b307733e491e43b-1759583550.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com. The endpoint was not immediately reachable. I guess due to DNS caching. After some minutes (5-10 minutes) waiting, i was able to call the http endpoint and got the nginx default start page.

Comment: Please give it a try and wait a bit, otherwise we should try a call and screen share. Hehe.

Comment: @Manuel First of all, thanks so much for the answer I hope u feel better. Where can we try a call, discord?

Comment: Please add me, then we can workout what's the issue here. Mino#3061

Comment: Request sent @Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small session, @xnextion and i figured out, why the service was not responding.

We checked the following points:

- Does the service selector points to the correct labels of the pod?
- Did the service generate endpoints resources?
- Is the pod working correctly? (Was a httpd container exposing port 80, curl localhost from the pod itself, to be sure, configuration is correct)
- Did the same call from another pod works?

Finally we figured out, that the pods and services was correct and it was a networkpolicy resource, which denied all traffic.